# Numeric Variable to string?

Tags: java, android, string, textview, format

So, here is the problem. I want to enter the number into text, so it shows like this "Number: 18" . But, for each user, number will be different, and that depends on user's answers. What function should I use do do it? I have been working in pawno before (for games), it was like

format(string, sizeof(string), "Number %d", number);

I tried this, but it does not seems to work. The text just becomes blank.
This is my whole code for that:

```
TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
              String string = "";
            format(string,256, "Your chances are %d % !",rezultat);
            tv6.setText(string);
```

Comment: isn't this working? : `String string = "Your chances are " + rezultat + " % !";`

Comment: Shouldn't the literal percent sign be `%%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
String string = "Your chances are " + rezultat + " % !";
```

Why your code not working ?

```
format(string,256, "Your chances are %d % !",rezultat);
```

`format()` will return the formatted string and will not format the string itself. (`String`s are immutable remember?) So you need to store its return in a string and then use it. Something like :

A.

```
String str = String.format(...);
tv6.setText(str);
```

B.

```
string = String.format(...);
tv6.setText(string);
```

C.

```
tv6.setText(String.format(...));
```

Also to print `%` in format you need to do write it like `%%`.

Comment: I am still having trouble, my app stops working... I used debbug tool, so it now just freezes, but not stops... And, if I delete this code, nothing happens (doesn't bug) Does string.format requires something like import or?

Comment: No it doesnt. Read http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html for more info.

Comment: I see format in italic, I think it is something about that, like something is missing... Because, if I enter this code, it does not crashes TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
           String str = "";
            tv6.setText(str);

Comment: by italic, maybe IDE is telling that the method id `STATIC`

Comment: Isnt't this working? `tv6.setText("Your chances are " + rezultat + " % !");`

Comment: Yeah, it works! I have tried it before, but I probably made some mistake, it is all good now! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
tv6.setText(String.format("Your chances are %d % !", rezultat));
```

Comment: I am still having trouble, my app stops working... I used debbug tool, so it now just freezes, but not stops... And, if I delete this code, nothing happens (doesn't bug) Does string.format requires something like import or?

Comment: I bet your `rezultat` is null, that's why you get exception and your app crashes.

Comment: No.. I tried with rezultat = 5; it stops... But, when I set like this TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
           String str = "";
            tv6.setText(str); it is all good...